# loc function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

Can anybody explain why is loc used in python pandas with examples like shown below?

```
for i in range(0, 2):
  for j in range(0, 3):
    df.loc[(df.Age.isnull()) & (df.Gender == i) & (df.Pclass == j+1),
            'AgeFill'] = median_ages[i,j]
```

Comment: In your example, `.loc` is used mainly because you try to access a cell via the column index `AgeFill`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The use of `.loc` is recommended here because the methods `df.Age.isnull()`, `df.Gender == i` and `df.Pclass == j+1` may return a view of slices of the data frame or may return a copy. This can confuse pandas.

If you don't use `.loc` you end up calling all 3 conditions in series which leads you to a problem called *chained indexing*. When you use `.loc` however you access all your conditions in one step and pandas is no longer confused.

You can read more about this along with some examples of when not using `.loc` will cause the operation to fail in the [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy).

The simple answer is that while you can often get away with not using `.loc` and simply typing (for example)

```
df['Age_fill'][(df.Age.isnull()) & (df.Gender == i) & (df.Pclass == j+1)] \
                                                          = median_ages[i,j]
```

you'll always get the `SettingWithCopy` warning and your code will be a little messier for it.

In my experience `.loc` has taken me a while to get my head around and it's been a bit annoying updating my code. But it's really super simple and very intuitive: `df.loc[row_index,col_indexer]`.

For more information see the pandas documentation on [Indexing and Selecting Data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html).